# Should s3:Replication:OperationFailedReplication Events be captured on the source or destination bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am setting up cross-region replication based on object tags.

I want to configure alerts so that I know when objects don't replicate.

I see that AWS offers a `s3:Replication:OperationFailedReplication` event.

Do I want to capture these events on my source bucket, or my destination bucket (where Objects are replicated to)?

The AWS Docs seem to make no explicit mention of this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to the AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-metrics.html)

```
To enable replication metrics by using the AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI), you must add a replication configuration to the source bucket with Metrics enabled.
```

In AWS S3, we create the replication rules on the source bucket and then enable the `Replication Metrics`. Once `Replication Metrics` are enabled, the following metrics are captured on the source bucket -

```
s3:Replication:*

s3:Replication:OperationFailedReplication

s3:Replication:OperationMissedThreshold

s3:Replication:OperationReplicatedAfterThreshold

s3:Replication:OperationNotTracked
```

The complete list of metrics can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations.html).

These events are emitted by the source bucket where the replication configuration is defined and apply to objects that are being replicated to the destination bucket.

Comment: I'm not so sure that's right. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/EventNotifications.html "To enable notifications, add a notification configuration that identifies the events that you want Amazon S3 to publish"